# Is there a better way to make this code shorter and without repetition?

Tags: python, function, selenium, web-scraping

I am improving my code making it easier to read, short and more dynamic.

I got the username and password hidden using dotenv.

As you can see first it opens a driver and then in the function, I ask the driver to get into the URL, then depends what account I put in the parameter the driver will access that specific email.

I already think of assigning the driver actions in multiple variables, but since the web login has 2 steps;

1. account and password
2. encrypted password

it can't be done like that.

Any thoughts?

```py
load_dotenv()


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
executable_path = {"executable_path": "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"}
browser = Browser("chrome", **executable_path, headless=False)
bw = browser.driver

html = browser.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


def open_web_email(account):
    """[This function will open web email]

    Arguments:
        account {[account]} -- [returns what email will open]
    """
    bw.get("https://webemail.com/login")
    bw.set_window_size(1080, 820)
    # username = bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]')
    # password = bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]')
    # login_butt = bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_btn"]')
    if account == "1":
        time.sleep(2)
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(os.getenv("P_USERNAME_ONE"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(os.getenv("P_PSW_ONE"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_btn"]').click()


        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mailboxPassword"]').send_keys(os.getenv("P_MAILBOX_ONE"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="unlock_btn"]').click()
    elif account == "2":
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(os.getenv("P_USERNAME_TWO"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(os.getenv("P_PSW_TWO"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_btn"]').click()


        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mailboxPassword"]').send_keys(os.getenv("P_MAILBOX_TWO"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="unlock_btn"]').click()
```

Maybe a better way to do it is using classes?

Comment: This seems more suitable to codereview... Not sure about their on-topic policy, but since you don't have an actual problem/error with your code I'm not sure this is the place...

Comment: Convenience link: [codereview.se]

Comment: thank you! didn't knew the existence of this website!

Answer (score 1):

You can create another method and pass arguments to that method to make it shorter. Based on your code only arguments are different

```
load_dotenv()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
executable_path = {"executable_path": "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"}
browser = Browser("chrome", **executable_path, headless=False)
bw = browser.driver

html = browser.html
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")


def open_web_email(account):
    """[This function will open web email]

    Arguments:
        account {[account]} -- [returns what email will open]
    """
    bw.get("https://webemail.com/login")
    bw.set_window_size(1080, 820)
    if account == "1":
        time.sleep(2)
        createAccount(P_USERNAME_ONE,P_PSW_ONE,P_MAILBOX_ONE)
    elseif account == "2":
        createAccount(P_USERNAME_TWO,P_PSW_TWO,P_MAILBOX_TWO)


def createAccount(username,password,mailBox)
{

        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="username"]').send_keys(os.getenv("username"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]').send_keys(os.getenv("password"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login_btn"]').click()


        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="mailboxPassword"]').send_keys(os.getenv("mailBox"))
        bw.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="unlock_btn"]').click()

}
```

Comment: thank you very much. Just one question. What does { } stands for?

Comment: In python its use to define data dictionary.